# Delete from SQL Server 2017 QueryStore dmv issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-query-store, dmv

We are using SentryOne, and one of the biggest consumers of IO & CPU resources is the query

```
delete sys.plan_persist_wait_stats
where Plan_id in (
    select plan_id
    from sys.plan_persist_plan
    where query_id = @query_id
)
```

I tried to Google it and all what I found is that it relates to the QueryStore.
I'm not able to access `sys.plan_persist_wait_stats` and `sys.plan_persist_plan` using Select command,
and they are not documented.

Any idea what to do?

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU26).

Comment: Do you have processes running `sys.sp_query_store_remove_query` or is this just from default behaviour?

Comment: @MartinSmith
No one uses it.

Comment: I guess that I'm not supposed to be exposed to the system activity and the system objects, mainly because I cannot have any influence on them: I cannot change the code, nor index the dmvs..
I wonder why this information is presented.. :-\

Comment: Yeah, seems like something you need to raise with Microsoft to look into - I remember SSIS also used to have inefficient cleanup routines and this was something that was fixed in a CU that added some missing indexes. You're not the only person to complain about this query https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/925ebeb8-4f2e-48a9-bf14-8ab6e88a5217/huge-io-amp-cpu-consumption-by-deletes-in-sysplanpersistruntimestats-by-querystore?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: The clustered index of `sys.plan_persist_wait_stats` is `plan_id` and it does have a non clustered index on `query_id` so I suppose any issue will be with `plan_persist_wait_stats` (has no index with leading column `plan_id` as CI is on `runtime_stats_interval_id, plan_id, wait_category, execution_type` and NCI is on `wait_stats_id`)